# R lme4ord installation error: "Error: object ‘sigma’ is not exported by 'namespace:lme4'"

Tags: r

I am trying to install lme4ord from github and receiving the following error:

`remotes::install_github("stevencarlislewalker/lme4ord")`

```
Downloading GitHub repo stevencarlislewalker/lme4ord@master
   checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpngUWJn/remotes2a0c5ce3f7b/stevencarlislewalker-lme4ord-5f62664/DESCRIP✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpngUWJn/remotes2a0c5ce3f7b/stevencarlislewalker-lme4ord-5f62664/DESCRIPTION’ (625ms)
─  preparing ‘lme4ord’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘lme4ord_0.0-3.tar.gz’

Installing package into ‘/home/localuserdir/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘lme4ord’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: object ‘sigma’ is not exported by 'namespace:lme4'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lme4ord’
* removing ‘/home/localuserdir/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/lme4ord’
Error: Failed to install 'lme4ord' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpngUWJn/file2a0c7b718e3a/lme4ord_0.0-3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

My sessionInfo is:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 30 (Workstation Edition)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] remotes_2.1.0 lme4_1.1-21   Matrix_1.2-17

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        magrittr_1.5      splines_3.6.0     MASS_7.3-51.4    
 [5] lattice_0.20-38   R6_2.4.0          minqa_1.2.4       tcltk_3.6.0      
 [9] tools_3.6.0       pkgbuild_1.0.3    grid_3.6.0        nlme_3.1-139     
[13] cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_1.3-2  
[17] crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.1    nloptr_1.2.1      callr_3.3.1      
[21] ps_1.3.0          curl_4.0          compiler_3.6.0    backports_1.1.4  
[25] prettyunits_1.0.2 boot_1.3-22
```

I have seen some discussions of namespace interactions (whether sigma is loaded from base or lme4) in earlier versions (3.2 or less) of R, but everything here should be up to date.
Any ideas?